# Why does this give me infinite loop?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I was trying to code a simple program:

```
import random

x = raw_input("How many rounds:")
rounds = 0

while rounds < x:
    # rock=0, paper=1, scissors=2
    computer1 = random.randint(0,2)
    computer2 = random.randint(0,2)

    if computer1 == computer2:
        print "draw"
    elif computer1 == 0 and computer2 == 1:
        print "lose"
    elif computer1 == 1 and computer2 == 2:
        print "lose"
    elif computer1 == 2 and computer2 == 0:
        print "lose"
    else:
        print "win"
    rounds = rounds + 1
```

Why does this give me an infinite loop? When I take out the input line and replace x with a certain value, say, 10, the output does give me 10 results. But why can't I do it with that raw_input?

Comment: Is this python 3? If so then by default all inputs will be `str` you need to cast to `int`

Comment: Because `int` < `str` is never going to be false. `while rounds < x`;

Comment: @EdChum That's also true of `raw_input` in Python 2 so it should definitely be fixed.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan didn't know what about python 2, for some reason thought this was different between python 2 and 3

Comment: @EdChum, `input` in `Python3` = `raw_input` in `Python2`. `input` in `Python2` has no correlate in `Python3` and tries to assume the type of the input automatically.

Comment: @EdChum @Scironic That's the gist of it. `ìnput` would technically work here but it's best to explicitly set it.

Comment: @Scironic thanks for the info, I don't use `input` and `raw_input` at all so it's useful to know this difference

Answer (score 10):

`raw_input` returns a string, you need to cast it to `int`

```
x = int(raw_input("How many rounds:"))
```

Note that in python:

```
>>> 159 < "8"
True
>>> 159 < 8
False
>>>
```

To better understand the `int`-`string` comparison, you can [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int).

Answer (score 4):

Change your input line to:

```
x = int(raw_input("How many rounds:"))
```

and you should be good to go. As pointed out in the comments, [the default raw_input is a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), and comparing an integer to a string won't give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since `raw_input()` always returns a `str` So for homogeneous comparison, You need to change the type of `x` to `int`

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("How many rounds:"))

rounds = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

And to be sure the user enters the needed value (i.g. "qwerty" or 2.6) you can add exception handling:

```
import random
try:
    x = input("How many rounds: ")
    rounds = 0
    while rounds < int(x):
        # rock=0, paper=1, scissors=2
        computer1 = random.randint(0,2)
        computer2 = random.randint(0,2)

        if computer1 == computer2:
            print ("draw")
        elif computer1 == 0 and computer2 == 1:
            print ("lose")
        elif computer1 == 1 and computer2 == 2:
            print ("lose")
        elif computer1 == 2 and computer2 == 0:
            print ("lose")
        else:
            print ("win")
        rounds = rounds + 1
except (ValueError):
    print('Wrong input')
```

This code is Python 3.